# Showing presence icon with sync adapter on contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-syncadapter, user-presence

I've tried to use the presence icon and show the presence for my custom users. 
no matter what i did I've encountered the failed to insert error or the presence was not showing on my contacts.

```
   values.put(StatusUpdates.DATA_ID, profileId);
   values.put(StatusUpdates.STATUS, user.getStatus());
   values.put(StatusUpdates.PROTOCOL, Im.PROTOCOL_CUSTOM);
   values.put(StatusUpdates.CUSTOM_PROTOCOL, CUSTOM_IM_PROTOCOL);
   values.put(StatusUpdates.IM_ACCOUNT, username);
   values.put(StatusUpdates.IM_HANDLE, user.getuserID());
   values.put(StatusUpdates.STATUS_RES_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName());
   values.put(StatusUpdates.STATUS_ICON, R.drawable.tray_icon);
   values.put(StatusUpdates.STATUS_LABEL, R.string.app_name);
   values.put(StatusUpdates.PRESENCE, StatusUpdates.AVAILABLE);
```

is there anyone with the solution?

Answer (score 1):

For a guide that includes special treatment for 2.2, permissions, etc. see also:

http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-1

http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-2

Their source is available:

https://github.com/c99koder/lastfm-android/

Answer (score 0):

This line looks suspicious:

`values.put(StatusUpdates.DATA_ID, profileId);`

What is profileId?  If specified, StatusUpdates.DATA_ID should be the _ID of the IM row in the "data" table.  You need to have that row before inserting a status.

The common practice is to have a row in the "data" table, then supply IM_PROTOCOL and IM_HANDLE (which is matched against Im.DATA), but leave DATA_ID unspecified in a status update insert.  ContactsProvider will match the status to the data row automatically and save you a lookup query.

Also, make sure you use bulkInsert for statuses if you can.  That will speed things up a lot.

Comment: thank you i will try it.
profileId is the rawcontact id i'm looking for in raw contacts table.
The user was inserted before and now i have a raw contact id that i'm using.
apparently not doing it right....